# Unable to preg_match tagged content

Tags: php, regex

I have a txt file which contains such data:

```
<!-- block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->some arbitrary data
<!-- end_block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 --> other data and other tags
```

However, when I try to match this content with a regular expression, I get nothing - just an empty array. This is what I have:

```
$regex = "`<!-- block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->(.*)<!-- end_block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->`";
$text = file_get_contents("txt.txt");
preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
echo strpos($text, "<!-- block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->") . "<BR/>";
echo strpos($text, "<!-- end_block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->") . "<BR/>";
print_r($matches);
```

As a result I get:

```
1178
59172
Array ( )
```

So, as you can see there is indeed `<!-- block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->` tag - it starts at index `1178`. And there is an ending tag `<!-- end_block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->` which starts at index `59172`. But why `$matches` is empty? And if I'm doing something wrong, what is the right way to get a tag and its contents using `preg_match`?

Comment: It is due to `\n`..use this `((.|\\n)*)` instead of `(.*)`..
Check here :- https://regex101.com/r/kB5vC2/1

Comment: you can use `backreference` as shown :- http://ideone.com/1ivkFI for simplicity

Comment: An alternative to @rock321987 solution is to include the `s` pattern modifier in your regex, like this: `$regex = "\`<!-- block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->(.*)<!-- end_block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->\`s";`. This will make the dot to match the newline as well.

Comment: @EduardoGalván Damn, I was searching for that but was unable to find it..I should have read the `flags` given on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using regexp *positive look-behind*(`?<=`) and *positive look-ahead (`?=`) assertions*:

```
$str = "<!-- block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 -->some arbitrary data
<!-- end_block_Inspekcionnye_proverki1000_1 --> other data and other tag";

preg_match("/(?<=-->)[\w ]+?\R?(?=<!--)/su", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some arbitrary data

)
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!